# how can I loging to webbrowser windows promt with autoit

Tags: authentication, phpmyadmin, prompt, autoit

I want to login to phpmyadmin, which popup a windows, is not a webform, is a prompt.

I don't have any idea about to get this thing done. My try is this, but i I don't know.

```
$oIE = _IECreate ("http://www.aersss.com/dh_phpmyadmin/mysql.aersss.com/index.php?db=mydb_compu_com")

_IELoadWait ($oIE)

Send("login")
Send("{tab}")
Send("password")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean basic authentication (phpMyAdmin can be set up to use this). In that case you can use the following:

```
http://username:password@www.aersss.com/dh_phpmyadmin/mysql.aersss.com/index.php?db=mydb_compu_com
```